# wordpress curl to codeigniter site

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, codeigniter, curl

I have a wordpress site that will login using a curl to another codeigniter website. After the login, the wordpress site should redirect to the dashboard of codeigniter site. 
I am not able to redirect the site. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```
$loginUrl = 'http://siteB.com/login/process';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,username='.$data['username'].'&password='.$data['password']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
$store = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://siteB.com/common/home/");
$page = curl_exec($ch);

echo $page;
curl_close($ch);
```

When I am viewing the chrome's developer tools, its response was the dashboard already so it seems that I have logged in already. How can I redirect the browser's page instead of viewing it only on response? I tried to use php header function after closing the curl but it doesn't work. By the way, I used ajax to curl.

Thanks.

Comment: You can't log in the user on their behalf this way (at least not without completely rebuilding the login process). What you've done is *log in your PHP script*

Comment: so how can I do that? any suggestion?

Comment: If you control both applications, there may be a SSO (single sign on) solution that integrates WP and CI. A Google search for `wordpress codeigniter sso` will help.